# "clang quit unexpectedly" (xcode Crash)

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.3, clang, llvm-clang

When i try to Analyze my code (Product -> Analyze), the xcode crash with this title "clang quit unexpectedly"

> Process:         clang [10074]
>   Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   Identifier:      clang
>   Version:         3.1 (318.0.61)
>   Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
>   Parent Process:  clang [10073]
>
> Date/Time:       2012-07-13 18:46:29.862 +0100
>   OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.4 (11E53)
>   Report Version:  9
>
> Interval Since Last Report:          140604 sec
>   Crashes Since Last Report:           50
>   Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   39
>   Anonymous UUID:                      E974A614-4831-478E-8B68-8FE005A98F19
>
> Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
>   Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
>
> VM Regions Near 0:
>   --> 
>       __TEXT                 000000010180f000-00000001029c8000 [ 17.7M] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>
> Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>   0   clang                           0x00000001018dc780 clang::Stmt::getSourceRange() const + 16
>   1   clang                           0x00000001021ce0c6 _ZL22getValidSourceLocationPKN5clang4StmtEN4llvm12PointerUnionIPKNS_15LocationContextEPNS_19AnalysisDeclContextEEE + 86
>   2   clang                           0x00000001021ce5d3 clang::ento::PathDiagnosticLocation::genLocation(clang::SourceLocation, llvm::PointerUnion) const + 35

my guest is because LLVM ? i have **Apple LLVM compiler 3.1**

Thanks!

Edit:
*Xcode Version 4.3.3 (4E3002)*

Comment: The clang shipping with Xcode has lots of bugs, especially in the (partially implementedd) C++11 features. It looks promising with the 6.0 SDK though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a file that always crashes clang when analyzed. I submitted abut report on it and Apple dupped the bug - so obviously they know of some bugs already. Note that Xcode 4.4 will be released in a week or two with llvm 4.0 so just wait for it, and if you still get crashes please enter a bug report at bug reporter.apple.com

Edit: my bug report was against 4.3.3

Comment: i updated xcode 4.4 with llvm 4.0 and now i can analyzed, no crash ;) thanks

Comment: Hah - I just feedback from Apple on my bug report - they said try Xcode 4.5 DP3 :-)